# summary of all bq jobs

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to list all job id's using bq command line tool for a given timeframe? What I need to do is to loop through all Id's and find if there is any error.

I use the web interface to know the job id and then use the command:

```
bq show -j --format=prettyjson job_id
```

Later I would manually copy paste the "error" part of the output. This takes a lot of time to report the job summary for a given day.

Comment: bq ls  -j `bq show | grep ^Project | awk '{print $2}'` | grep "`date +'%d %b'`" | awk '{print $1}' # this is poor man's solution is not as elegant as shown below

Comment: actually, piping the result into a stream processor can be pretty elegant :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, you can list up to the last 1,000 jobs for a project you have access to by running:

```
bq  ls -j --max_results=1000 project_number
```

If you have more than 1,000 jobs, you can also write a Python script to list *all jobs* by paging through results in batches of 1,000 - like so:

```
import httplib2
import pprint
import sys

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError

from oauth2client.client import AccessTokenRefreshError
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import run


# Enter your Google Developer Project number
PROJECT_NUMBER = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'

FLOW = flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secrets.json',
                               scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery')



def main():

  storage = Storage('bigquery_credentials.dat')
  credentials = storage.get()

  if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = run(FLOW, storage)

  http = httplib2.Http()
  http = credentials.authorize(http)

  bigquery_service = build('bigquery', 'v2', http=http)
  jobs = bigquery_service.jobs()

  page_token=None
  count=0

  while True:
    response = list_jobs_page(jobs, page_token)
    if response['jobs'] is not None:
      for job in response['jobs']:
        count += 1
        print '%d. %s\t%s\t%s' % (count,
                                  job['jobReference']['jobId'],
                                  job['state'],
                                  job['errorResult']['reason'] if job.get('errorResult') else '')
    if response.get('nextPageToken'):
      page_token = response['nextPageToken']
    else:
      break


def list_jobs_page(jobs, page_token=None):
  try:
    jobs_list = jobs.list(projectId=PROJECT_NUMBER,
                          projection='minimal',
                          allUsers=True,
                          maxResults=1000,
                          pageToken=page_token).execute()

    return jobs_list

  except HttpError as err:
    print 'Error:', pprint.pprint(err.content)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: # getting an error # oauth2client.clientsecrets.InvalidClientSecretsError: File not found: "client_secrets.json"

Comment: Yeah, the above script requires a client id and secret, as it uses OAuth... See: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorization#clientsecrets

Comment: You can also write these scripts using server-to-server service account auth (actually, this is a better strategy for automated scripts that live on a server)... see here: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorization#service-accounts-server

Comment: Note that the job list should be returned with the most recent jobs first; you may not need to list all jobs over all time. As the number of jobs you have grows, the performance is likely to get pretty poor if you try to iterate over all of your jobs. If you do something like this, I'd suggest adding early termination to stop at the first job older than the date you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The following shell script is close to what I need to report.

```
#!/bin/sh
bq ls  -j `bq show | grep ^Project | awk '{print $2}'` | grep "`date +'%d %b'`" | awk '{print $1}' > tosave.txt

for myjob in `cat tosave.txt`
do
bq ls  -j `bq show | grep ^Project | awk '{print $2}'` | grep $myjob

bq show --format=prettyjson -j $myjob | grep -C2 "message" | head

done
```